# Office taskpane add-in not loading after hosting it online

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, ms-office, office-js, office-addins

I built a taskpane add in. Everything works fine in development with commands like `npm start`etc. I now deployed my plugin as web app on azure. I then exchanged all references to my new url instead of localhost in the `manifest.xml` and named it `manifest2.xml`. However when trying to sideload it with `office-addin-debugging start manifest2.xml`I just see in powerpoint:

[image]

The web app is reachable with my browser and has an `https`url.
Manifest looks like this:

```
  <DefaultSettings>
    <SourceLocation DefaultValue="https://appname.azurewebsites.net/taskpane.html"/>
  </DefaultSettings>
```

The docker image is built like this:

```
FROM node:14.2.0-alpine3.10 as build
RUN echo "*** Build Phase ***"
WORKDIR .
ENV PATH ./node_modules/.bin:$PATH
COPY package.json ./
COPY package-lock.json ./
RUN npm ci
COPY . ./
RUN npm run build

FROM nginx:stable-alpine
RUN echo "*** Deployment Phase ***"
COPY --from=build ./dist /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

Answer (score 0):

> I now deployed my plugin as web app on azure

Unless you have a web app running on the server the add-in files will not be accessible. So, instead, you need to upload the add-in files to the storage, not as a web app without a reason. See [Static website hosting in Azure Storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-static-website) for more information about hosting such apps.

Comment: That's interesting, I wanted to use the wb app service, since I can hook it up with AzureDevOps have auth integrations, certificate handling and so on. As far as I understand, static website hosting doesn't support these kind of things. Would static web apps be an alternative? https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/app-service/static/

Comment: That is a separate question, I'd suggest posting a separate question for Azure specific features. If you need to use a web app consider using express.js for running a server to serve add-in files.

Comment: sure, I will do that. But to be clear, I actually have a server that serves the add in files. I will edit my post with the docker setup.

Comment: so if I understood you correctly, it being a web app is not what causes the problem, since the files are accessible?

Comment: I was able to run the add-in hosted in Azure as a web app. Just make sure add-in files are accessible in a web browser by navigating to them and all dependencies were installed correctly.